# DB2 connectivity to UNIX

Tags: unix, db2, sh, csh

I am fairly new to UNIX and have been trying to write a script and connect to DB2 database.
I googled a lot about the Db2 connectivity to UNIX and was able to gather these points:

1. Db2 requires setting the environment path. So I set the path using the command:

`setenv PTH ${PATH}:/opt/IBM/db2client/V9.5.FP4a/bin`

2. Then there was something about creating DB2 profiles and DB2 instances but I failed to understand anything.

Can someone be generous enough and explain me step-by-step how to connect to Db2 through Unix. The shell I am using is CSH.

Thank you.

Comment: Although your shell is csh, can you check if either ksh or bash is installed?  The reason is that ksh or bash are very much more shell-scripting friendly (you can remain with csh but your scripts can be ksh or bash, which will work fine). These may be in /bin/bash or /usr/bin/ksh .  Also it helps if you know *which kind* of Db2-client is installed , and what flavour of Unix. A Db2-client can be either instance-less or have an inststance (which is just a collection of settings on a client) and the type of the Db2-client tells us this.

Comment: You may want to start here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/Big%20Data%20University/page/FREE%20eBook%20-%20Getting%20Started%20with%20DB2%20Express-C